# source code for Firefox WebDriver (firefox extension)?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, google-webdriver

When I use Selenium 2(Webdriver) with the Firefox driver, a Firefox extension is loaded into Firefox. I would like to see the source code of this Firefox extension and modify some things. I tried looking for the source code but was unable to find it. Is the source code available for download and modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/firefox-driver/, which is the extension source.

Comment: They moved it [to github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/firefox-driver)

Answer (score 0):

You can find selenium source in below link.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout

As it is open source you can download it your machine & do custmizations.

Comment: Not really sure what the downvote was for here...yes it doesn't link directly to it, but it links to the overall 'container' if you will, so +1.